# Be able to see elided Ibuffer entries

Tags: ibuffer

I am using Ibuffer for better buffer management and the display format is set to elide long buffer names. This is good but sometimes I would also like to see the full name (like when positioning the point over the buffer entry). Is there a way to ask IBuffer to display the full name (non elided), lets say, in the minibuffer when the point is over a buffer line?

There are lots of posts around on how to change the ibuffer format string to accommodate longer buffer names but this is not exactly the same thing: sometimes the buffer names (or the paths for example) are so long that they cannot reasonably fit the screen so leaving lots of space for them in the format string would be counter productive. However having a way to quickly see the full name would be great!

**EDIT:** After some searching around: when the line below (where the minibuffer appears) is used to display a message then it is called *echo area*.

There is a special *text property* that is called *help-echo* that is made especially for tool-tip style applications as described in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html). The hint assigned by ibuffer to these entries is the tool-tip that gets displayed on mouse hover:

```
mouse-1: mark this buffer
mouse-2: select this buffer
mouse-3: operate on this buffer.
```

As described once again by the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Help-Echo.html) this can be automatically displayed in the *echo area* by setting **help-at-pt-display-when-idle** to *t*.

However this would ruin mouse tool-tips; maybe one could/should implement this as a configurable option. Another option would be the **point-entered** text property.

I have only a very approximate idea of how to actually implement this change. Any suggestions are welcome.